# Amazon Alexa says my json is invalid and I dont know what to do to fix it

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, alexa-skills-kit

I'm making an Alexa flash briefing skill and need to return json from my URL. I have the following in my homecontroller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Feed(string id)
{
    Helper.TodaysWord help = new Helper.TodaysWord();
    return Content(help.jsonBuilder(id), "application/json");
}
```

Going to the URL gives me the following json.

```
{"uid":"7a257633-4032-4593-a1be-a354a395aced","updateDate":"2/28/2018 12:00:00 AM","titleText":"Today's Japanese","mainText":"Test, put word and definition here","redirectionUrl":"HTTP://www.LostDutchmanSoftware.com"}
```

I get "Error: There was an error parsing the feed. Please ensure that the feed is valid JSON or RSS." when amazon try's to validate the source. I'm really new to this please help.

Comment: Is this a dateformat issue? I think in Amazon json you need dates in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.0Z'.` - so like this `"updateDate": "2017-04-13T21:15:11.0Z",`

Comment: Thank you Mr JF, I'll try that right now I bet that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is valid. Your issue might be related to date format.

Try using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format which is very common.

> "updateDate" : "2018-02-28T12:00:00.0Z"

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: Worked, the date format was the only problem. Thank you so much mdemir!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Nice steal @mdemir :)